# RDCOMClient R package does not find emails by sender

Tags: r, outlook

I am trying to search emails by sender using the RDCOMClient package.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
outlook_app <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")

search <- outlook_app$AdvancedSearch(
    "Inbox",
    "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail = 'test@XYZ.com'"
)

Sys.sleep(10)

results <- search$Results()
results$Count()
```

However, this does not return any emails. Searching by subject using "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject = 'test'" works.

What's potentially happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `AdvancedSearch` is asynchronous, you need to wait for the results to become available. Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` (where `Items` collection comes from `MAPIFOlder.Items`, and `MAPIFolder` can be retrieved from `Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`).

Comment: Yes, I know it is asynchronous. Hence, the Sys.sleep(10). However, it still does not work (it finds 0 mail items regardless of the mail address) while searching for subjects works fine. Is "fromemail" even correct here? Could you spell out the second sentence more in terms of R or in general? I have a hard time following.

Comment: sleep() won't make it run synchronously, you'd have to wait for the `Application.AdvancedSearchComplete` event to fire.

Comment: I know nothing about R, but you need to open the inbox using `Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`, then use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`

Comment: Thanks for your help - I think i figured the problem. It works with external mails but internal mails are not stored as smtp addresses by default. Will link to the other SO answer later.